# Data from fetch displaying on page, but isolating a property results in undefined value

Tags: graphql, vuejs3, strapi, nuxtjs3

I am using Nuxt 3 and I have a composable set up to do graphQL queries.

As you can see in my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-zwcm2g?file=app.vue,composables%2FuseGQL.js) the data is coming in fine.
However I can't seem to target a property with a path. If you uncomment the path you will see the error.
I have tried using v-if to check that the data exists before targetting , perhaps I need a different condition. Will keep trying here and update if I find a way.

edit: So I found a solution but I would love to know why it works. In the fetch , I returned json.data instead of json. I won't post an answer because it would not be a thorough one! Hoping for someone with a thorough grasp of why one can't use the json object as is , as opposed to using the 'data' attribute on it.

Answer (score 1):

The response body returned by Strapi is in the form of

```
{
  "data": {
    ...
  },
  "meta":{}
}
```

Calling `json()` returns the response body as JSON, but you still have to select the `data` key.

See https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest-api.html#requests

Comment: Thanks Sjouke...  makes sense now. Was confused between the 'data' ref returned by the composable and the 'data' key in the json